# OSX: How to get a volume name (or bsd name) from a IOUSBDeviceInterface or location id

Tags: macos, usb, iokit

I'm trying to write an app that associates a particular USB string descriptor (of a USB mass storage device) with its volume or bsd name.

So the code goes through all the connected USB devices, gets the string descriptors and extracts information from one of them.  I would like to get the volume name of those USB devices.  I can't find the right API to do that.
I have tried to do that:

```
DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
DADiskRef disk_ref = DADiskCreateFromIOMedia(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                             session,
                                             usb_device_ref);
const char* name = DADiskGetBSDName(disk_ref);
```

But the DADiskCreateFromIOMedia function returned nil, I assume the usb_device_ref that I passed was not compatible with the io_service_t that the function is expecting.

So how can I get the volume name of a USB device?

Could I use the location id to do that?

Thanks for reading.
-L

```
FOO_Result              result = FOO_SUCCESS;
mach_port_t             master_port;
kern_return_t           k_result;
io_iterator_t           iterator = 0;
io_service_t            usb_device_ref;
CFMutableDictionaryRef  matching_dictionary = NULL; 

// first create a master_port
if (FOO_FAILED(k_result = IOMasterPort(MACH_PORT_NULL, &master_port))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "could not create master port, err = %d\n", k_result);
    goto cleanup;
}
if ((matching_dictionary = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName)) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "could not create matching dictionary, err = %d\n", k_result);
    goto cleanup;
}
if (FOO_FAILED(k_result = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(master_port, matching_dictionary, &iterator))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "could not find any matching services, err = %d\n", k_result);
    goto cleanup;
}
while (usb_device_ref = IOIteratorNext(iterator))
{       
    IOReturn                        err;
    IOCFPlugInInterface             **iodev;        // requires <IOKit/IOCFPlugIn.h>
    IOUSBDeviceInterface            **dev;
    SInt32                          score;

    err = IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService(usb_device_ref, kIOUSBDeviceUserClientTypeID, kIOCFPlugInInterfaceID, &iodev, &score);
    if (err || !iodev)
    {
        printf("dealWithDevice: unable to create plugin. ret = %08x, iodev = %p\n", err, iodev);
        return;
    }
    err = (*iodev)->QueryInterface(iodev, 
                                   CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(kIOUSBDeviceInterfaceID), 
                                   (LPVOID*)&dev);
    (*iodev)->Release(iodev);               // done with this


    FOO_String string_value;
    UInt8 string_index = 0x1;
    FOO_Result result = FOO_SUCCESS;
    CFStringRef device_name_as_cf_string;
    do {
        if (FOO_SUCCEEDED(result = FOO_GetStringDescriptor(dev, string_index, 0, string_value))) {
            printf("String at index %i is %s\n", string_index, string_value.GetChars());
            // extract the command code if it is the FOO string
            if (string_value.CompareN("FOO:", 4) == 0) {
                FOO_Byte code = 0;
                FOO_HexToByte(string_value.GetChars() + 4, code);
                // Get other relevant information from the device
                io_name_t        device_name;
                UInt32           location_id = 0;

                // Get the USB device's name.
                err = IORegistryEntryGetName(usb_device_ref, device_name);
                device_name_as_cf_string = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, device_name, 
                                                                     kCFStringEncodingASCII); 

                err = (*dev)->GetLocationID(dev, &location_id);

                // TODO: get volume or BSD name 

                // add the device to the list

                break;
            }
        }
        string_index++;
    } while (FOO_SUCCEEDED(result));


    err = (*dev)->USBDeviceClose(dev);
    if (err)
    {
        printf("dealWithDevice: error closing device - %08x\n", err);
        (*dev)->Release(dev);
        return;
    }
    err = (*dev)->Release(dev);
    if (err)
    {
        printf("dealWithDevice: error releasing device - %08x\n", err);
        return;
    }

    IOObjectRelease(usb_device_ref);            // no longer need this reference
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have the io_service_t, you can recurse through the IORegistry to find the BSD Name. You do not need to actually create an interface.

```
#import <IOKit/IOBSD.h>

CFStringRef bsdName = ( CFStringRef ) IORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty ( usbDevice,
                                                                       kIOServicePlane,
                                                                       CFSTR ( kIOBSDNameKey ),
                                                                       kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                       kIORegistryIterateRecursively );
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the same as a bsd name but I get the devices name like this: io_name_t deviceName; IORegistryEntryGetName(usbDevice, deviceName);

Comment: thanks @Alex, it's the one I wanted. bsdName not always useful, and not always returns something. However it's possible that the context is not exactly the same than for the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

See also:

usbdevs - list mounted USB devices & their volume paths on Mac OS X

https://gist.github.com/atr000/621561

Comment: Seems correct. Didn't try it, the solution from @Alex did the job.